# About the use of the maximum principle for ODE's

Tags: analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Show that a solution from $u''-2\cos(u')=1$ can´t reach a local maximum.

I think this proble needs more information to be solve or to find the answer to the question.

Anyway, how can I use the maximum strong principle in order to find the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HINT. It's easier than you think. At a local maximum $x_0$ you must have $u'(x_0)=0$ and $u''(x_0)$ can either vanish or have a sign (which one, positive or negative?). Use this to show that a local maximum cannot exist.

Alternatively, you can try to determine the convexity of any solution to the given equation.